# linear transformations with matrices $A, A^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Let $K$ be a field, $K\subseteq \Bbb C$. $V$ is a linear space over $K$, $\dim(V)=n(n\geq2)$. Choose ordered basis $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\dotsc,\epsilon_n$ for $V$.

$\bf A,B$ are two linear transformations from $V$ to $V$, with transformation matrices $A, A^*$ relative to the ordered basis , respectively.  ($A^*$ is the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$). then

1). $\bf AB=\bf BA$

2). Let $M=\{\alpha\in V|\bf B\alpha =0\}$. If $0$ is a eigenvalue of $\bf A$, Can one find a basis of $M$?

For 1), Since $AA^*=A^*A$ , so $\bf AB=\bf BA$

For 2), $\dim(M)=n $ or $n-1$. But what is a basis of $M$?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: $AA^{\ast} = A^{\ast} A$ is false for general matrices $A$. The same is true for $AB = BA$. Even if $AA^{\ast} = A^{\ast}A$, this would not imply $AB = BA$.

Comment: @PhoemueX The question is a bit confusing. The OP says that "$A^\ast$ is the **adjugate** matrix of $A$", not the Hermitian adjoint of $A$. If he/she really means that, then $A^\ast$ does commute with $A$.

Comment: Oh, of course. But nevertheless, it will never imply $AB = BA$.

Comment: @PhoemueX $Hom(V,V)$ is isomorphism to $M_n(K)$

Comment: dim$(M)=0$ only if $B$ is the zero transformation...in which case $A$ is also the zero transformation.

Comment: @ChristiaanHattingh If $B$ is the zero transformation, It seems that $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\dotsc,\epsilon_n$ a basic of $M$

Comment: @Clin yes it is. basically then $M=V$

Comment: ah sorry, I was wrong, if $B$ is the zero transformation $A$ is not necessarily also the zero transformation...it just means $A$ is rank $n-2$ or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $A^*A=\det(A)I=0$, so that the columns of $A$ is in $M$, and $M$ is not trivial - so yes, then we can find a basis for $M$. How? Well , the same as for finding the kernel of any linear transformation...just solve the homogenous system with coefficient matrix, the matrix representation of the linear transformation, in this case $A^*$.

For further investigation: does the columns of $A$ span $M$? If so, then the basis can just be derived by finding a linearly independent subset from the columns of $A$.

---

Edit. After thinking about it I realized, if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and $A$ is rank $n-1$, then the columns of $A$ do indeed span $M$, as there is at least one nonzero cofactor of some entry in $A$ so that $A^*$ is not the zero matrix.

And if $A$ is rank $n-2$ or less, then all the cofactor matrices of the entries of $A$ are rank deficient, so that $A^*=0$ and so then $V=M$.

Comment: Thank you very much! If $\dim(M)=n-1$. Without loss of generality, the first $n-1$ columns of $A$ span . then, is $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\dotsc,\epsilon_{n-1}$ a basic of $M$?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: If $rank(A)=n-1$. then $\dim(M)=n-1$. Without loss of generality, the first $n-1$ columns $\alpha_1, \dotsc,\alpha_{n-1}$ of $A$ is a basis of $\alpha_1, \dotsc,\alpha_n$, then $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\dotsc,\epsilon_n)\alpha_1, \dotsc,(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\dotsc,\epsilon_n)\alpha_{n-1} $  is a basis of $M$

Comment: $\alpha_1, \dotsc,\alpha_{n-1}$ is the coordinate vectors of a set of vectors, which is basis for $M$ - this is what you mean? I think you are right. If rank$(A)=n-1$ then $\dim(M)$ is at least $n-1$, and since $A^*$ cannot be the zero matrix in this case, we must have $\dim(M)=n-1$ so that there is some set of $n-1$ columns of $A$ which is a basis for $M$ (or, are the coordinate vectors of the basis).

Comment: So if the first $n-1$ columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then A$(\epsilon_i)$, $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ is a basis for $M$ (where A in this case indicates the linear transformation)